# Anaconda 3 Python command appears to be broken

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

This is probably an error on my part but, after combing the web, I have been unable to find an answer. I have an environment in Anaconda called `p36` (unimaginative, I know) that should reference a Python 3.6 install. However, when I run `python`, I do not see the expected shell and prompt, but rather this:

```
python : Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python 3.6.6 |A...MD64)] on win32:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Type
 "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
>>
```

That looks like the Python interpreter threw a `RemoteException` to me. My Anaconda environment is:

```
     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\ME\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\ME\.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.9
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\ME\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.9 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

And I have the environment activated, as you can see:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3
p36                   *  C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs\p36
testcreate               C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs\testcreate
```

And I'm running this all on Powershell ISE 5.1 build 17134 revision 165

UPDATE: When I attempted to run `conda install -y scrapy` I got the exception again, although it didn't stop the process from proceeding. I think it may be a problem with Anaconda.

UPDATE 2: I can run `ipython` ... sort of. This is my output:

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

However, I am unable to type into the interpreter and it appears to be completely unresponsive (I have to `CTRL+C` to exit)

Any help in fixing this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out, by realizing that the issue wasn't related to anaconda at all, but rather any and all I/O I was trying to do. I was running Powershell ISE, with ISE being the operative term. Powershell supports interactive commands but Powershell ISE doesn't, as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/02/04/console-application-non-support-in-the-ise/). To get around this issue, you can either run vanilla Powershell or install another command prompt, like [ConEmu](https://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html), which is what I did.

As an aside, I was aware of Powershell beforehand but I chose ISE because vanilla Powerhsell doesn't support 日本語, or any unicode characters really, which I very much needed for what I was trying to do.

Comment: Glad you figured it out @Woody1193

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I owe you thanks as well. It was you asking me to run `ipython` that made me realize the issue wasn't related to anaconda's python install, but rather something else

Comment: No worries, it is all good, solving these sort of problems can be frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem, you probably need to activate the environment before launching ipython:

on command line:

`source activate p36` (or `activate p36` on windows?)

then:

`ipython`

When you are done:

`source deactivate` (or `deactivate` on windows?)

You can get a list of the conda environments with:

`conda list`

Comment: My apologies but I forgot to mention that in the original question. The environment was activated. Besides that, if nothing was activated then the base environment should've run the normal python environment, yeah?

Comment: ok, no worries. did you try launching `ipython` i/o python? BTW, the report first line shows `active environment : None`, maybe it means something?

Comment: That's really weird. I don't get any exceptions running `ipython` but I can't actually interact with the shell either

Comment: Not sure what "I can't actually interact with the shell either" means; can you elaborate a little bit, and describe what precisely happens when you launch ipython? (it should launch the ipython interactive console --> starts with `In [1]: []` after a few lines detailing the python version, etc...